Reading Float data with float variable in stored procedure rounds numbers
In SQL Server Management Studio:
DECLARE @Amount FLOAT

SELECT SUM(Amount) 
FROM Docs 
WHERE DocID IN (104482, 104483, 104484, 104486, 104489, 104491, 104493)

-- displays in results window 178457,05

SELECT @Amount = SUM(Amount) 
FROM Docs 
WHERE DocID IN (104482, 104483, 104484, 104486, 104489, 104491, 104493)

PRINT @Amount

Displays in messages window an actually assigns to variable  178457
I get 178457 but 178457,05 is correct.
Why is it rounding values to a length of 7 digits?
Any ideas how to assign correct data to the float variable?

SQL Server Management Studio 19.3.4.0
SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) 16.200.48053
Microsoft T-SQL Parser 17.0.27.
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools 16.0.20054.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 10.0.22621.3958
Microsoft MSXML 3.0 6.0
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.30319.42000
Windows Operating System 10.0.22631


I could not find a perfect link to explain this behaviour but I think it is related to how print command deals with float, best I could find was this: Converting float and real data. Try doing this: PRINT CAST(@Amount AS DECIMAL(10, 2)); instead. I can add an answer if that works for you.

Thanks Jorge, If i declare the variable as  DECIMAL(10, 2) instead of FLOAT  solves the issue,

FYI, the version details of SSMS  is completely irrelevant here. If it's version specific, it's the version of SQL Server we need to know.

Also, float is almost always the wrong data type. Only use that data type when you need to store very large or very small values and precision isn't an issue.

Telling us about the SSMS version is like telling us the car you drive is a Sony, because that's the brand you see on the dashboard radio: fine for some, but alarming from a mechanic. This time, at least, there's enough info in the question we can know you're using SQL Server. But that's like finally knowing you're driving a Ford, without even knowing whether it's a Ford Explorer or Ford Mustang, let alone what kind of engine is under the hood, or what model year.

Ok, I didn't notice that in the about info of the Managment studio it didn't show the version of of the database, (because you can connect to different datase versions at the same time).    However in the same Managment studio it correctly displayed the data from a float field in the results tab, but it didn't correctly assign the data from a float field to a float variable.
